# Is there a way to make JQuery animation not relative?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I am making a picture move to a location, and then it redirects to a page where the picture SHOULD be in the same location. With all of this being relative, it's not working so well.
What I would like to do is something where the final result will be the picture is 5% from the top, and 5% from the left. I am having so much trouble!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Picture').fadeIn(1000).delay(1500).animate({'top': '2%', 'left': '-=37%', 'height': '-=50px'},2000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `-=` (or `+=`) part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Picture').fadeIn(1000)
                 .delay(1500)
                 .animate({
                    'top': '5%',
                    'left': '5%'
                 }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble though with the left animation. The picture is moving to the right slightly (probably the 5% I now set it to). It starts in the center if that is any help.

Comment: @Matt, Adjust the percentage values to match the position of the image on the new page, or did I understand you incorrectly?

Comment: I've tried that, but if the browser changes sizes, it no longer matches?

Comment: @Matt, what if you used `px` positioning instead?